# Connect to client's PC to access files using php or JS

Tags: php, javascript

Here is what I'm trying to achieve.

Write a php or JS program on my server that connects to a client's PC (outside of our network) and reads files or copies them to our server.

The client folder to read is going to be the same, ex: C:\MyCSV, although subfolder names will change.

My server runs Linux, it is sufficient to assume the client has a PC, not a MAC or Linux.

I'm not looking for code, I would like to know if this is possible using PHP or JS

Comment: Unfortunately, SO is not a Research Assistant, please refer to [What Can I Ask Here](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) to see what is appropriate to ask. Please provide specific questions, examples about what have you tried, or what the specific problem is.

Comment: Apologies if it sounded like I wanted code. I've edited the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to make an HTML interface for the user to select and upload files, and for PHP to receive those files and act on them. But you can't just get free access to the remote user's filesystem.

If your client has a static IP address, they could potentially set up a SSH server or some other secure remote login protocol, allowing your script to log in to their machine and get the files. You would need to work with them to make sure that this was done securely and didn't create any unnecessary vulnerabilities.

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not possible. PHP can access local directories when it is hosted (via local server) on that machine, but not from a remote server.

The user would have to first upload the contents of the directory.

JS is even more out of the question as it's a client-side language and, therefore, has even more stringent security restrictions.

Answer (score 0):

Without user intervention, that, may us think, and browser developpers too, that you are trying to stole files from user computer. So we will be to critic to you, and browser developpers won't include a legacy way to do that.

The normal and necessary "user intervention" is to browse to the file that you want to be uploaded to the server.